# Replacing [+] View list of options I selected using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML page where there are many urls like this, what i am trying to do is replace all instances of [+] View list of options I selected with a Twist.

What i want to do is if `Help_CartItemDetails.php?CartID=1` the `[+] View list of options I selected` should be replaced with 1, if `Help_CartItemDetails.php?CartID=2` the `[+] View list of options I selected` should be replaced with 2  and soon... is this possible in jquery..

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:OpenNewWindow('Help_CartItemDetails.php?CartID=1', '425', '300');">
[+] View list of options I selected</a>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:OpenNewWindow('Help_CartItemDetails.php?CartID=2', '425', '300');">
[+] View list of options I selected</a>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:OpenNewWindow('Help_CartItemDetails.php?CartID=3', '425', '300');">
[+] View list of options I selected</a>
```

Comment: post your `OpenNewWindow` function too

Comment: What do you mean by replaced by 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

yes try something to the effect of

```
$("a").click(function(){
     $(this).html(this.id);
});
```

it's simplest if you just add id's, otherwise you would replace the `this.id`, with something a lot more complicating.